TypeError: _azure_openai__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AzureKeyCredential is not a constructor
I'm doing a project to make a chatbot that can read my portfolio. I'm using the Azure OpenAi GPT-3.5 model and have configured my API key and endpoint. I'm currently testing the API calls with a simple GET request. This code is in a file called "route.js" :
import { AzureCliCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import { OpenAIClient, AzureKeyCredential } from "@azure/openai";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const endpoint = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT;
const apiKey = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY;
const model = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL;

export async function GET(req) {
  const client = new OpenAIClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));

  const messages = [
    {
      role: "system",
      content: "You are a helpful assistant.",
    },
    {
      role: "user",
      content: "Why is python such a popular coding language?",
    },
  ];

  const response = await client.getChatCompletions(model, messages, {
    maxTokens: 128,
  });

  return NextResponse.json({
    message: response.choices[0].message.content,
  });
}


However, I get this error message in the terminal:

I have tried other methods but they all lead back to this 1 error.
I tried searching the documentation online and changing the import syntax, but the problem remains.


TypeError:azure_openai__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_.AzureKeyCredential is not a constructor

The error was caused by an issue with the @azure/openai package. We need to use the openai package when working with JavaScript. Install the openai package using the following command:
npm install openai

I updated the code to use the OpenAI package and the POST request method to get output in the browser for any question I ask.
Code :
route.js :
import { AzureOpenAI } from "openai";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const endpoint = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT;
const apiKey = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY;
const deployment = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL;
const apiVersion = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_APIVERSION;


export async function POST(req) {
    try {
        const client = new AzureOpenAI({
            apiKey,
            endpoint,
            deployment,
            apiVersion
        });

        const requestBody = await req.json();
        const messages = requestBody.messages || [];
        
        const result = await client.chat.completions.create({
            messages,
            model: "",
        });

        return NextResponse.json({
            message: result.choices[0].message.content,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching chat completions:", error);
        return NextResponse.json({
            error: "Failed to fetch response from OpenAI.",
        });
    }
}

page.js :
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");

  const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/bot", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            messages: [{ role: "user", content: question }],
        }),
    }); 
      const data = await res.json();
      setResponse(data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching response:", error);
      setResponse("Failed to fetch response.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "20px" }}>
      <h1>Welcome to My Portfolio Chatbot</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Ask a question"
        style={{ padding: "10px", width: "300px", margin: "10px 0" }}
        value={question}
        onChange={(e) => setQuestion(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <button
        style={{ padding: "10px 20px", cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Answer
      </button>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <p>{response}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

.env.local :
AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT=https://<openai_name>.openai.azure.com/
AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY=<api_key>
AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL=gpt-35-turbo
AZURE_OPENAI_APIVERSION=2024-05-01-preview

Output :

Browser Output :
I received the correct response in the browser when I asked a question in my chatbot portfolio, as shown below.


Thank you so much!!! You are amazing!!!!!
